# Elasticsearch parallel bulk update or index first

Tags: python, elasticsearch

So in my project I am adding a bulk update function using Elasticsearch's parallel bulk helper function. This is what my update function looks like:

```
action = {
  "_id": id,
  "_op_type": "update",
  "_index": some_index,
  "doc": {'some_key': 'some_value'}
}
ACTIONS.append(action)

# run the bulk operations
for success, info in parallel_bulk(self.es, ACTIONS, index=some_index):
```

and I have an index function as such below:

```
action = {
  "_id": id,
  "_op_type": "index",
  "_source": payloads[id],
}
ACTIONS.append(action)

# run the bulk operations
for success, info in parallel_bulk(self.es, ACTIONS, index=some_index):
```

My question is, should I be using the update function (meant to add the doc field onto each record) first or index all the records first? It seems to work doing it both ways but I wanted to know if one is supposed to come after the other.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index` command is supposed to come first to create a first version of the document and then you can update your documents using the `update` command.

`update` should be considered when all you want to do is to partially update some document, i.e. only a few fields.

`index` should be considered if you want to overwrite the full document with a new version. This operation is also faster that `update` because it doesn't need to first retrieve the existing version of the document, update it, delete the old version and reindex the new version.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer! I am using the update function because there are certain records that need to have a specific field appended to it.